# requireSSL="true" for subfolder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-2.0

Is it possible to set requireSSL="true" for admin part of the site alone?

Comment: Sorry I actually meant requireSSL="true" for the HTTPCookies.. I want to make the session cookies secure.. setting requireSSL="true" in HTTPCookies tag in web.config is doing the trick but I need this work for admin part alone.. 
I checked and seems this setting can be done only from the root web.config and will affect the entire website. 
The authentication cookie am creating manually and making secure by setting cookie.Secure = true; but am looking for someways to make the session cookie also secure for the admin part alone..

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily for any page:

```
If HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(False) Then
    Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl) 
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For older versions of IIS, the procedure is to open the IIS manager and right-click on the folder you want to require SSL on, and choose properties.  The go to the Security tab just like you would on an entire web site or web app.

I am relatively sure it works the same on the newer versions, but I haven't yet had hands-on experience with anything above IIS 6.  However, this is such a common requirement, I'm sure it's the same.

([official iis instructions here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/56bdf977-14f8-4867-9c51-34c346d48b04.mspx?mfr=true))